# getimagesize works for some images and not others

Tags: php, getimagesize

I have the following script that returns the height and width of the image on my local server using PHP 5.2.6, but not on my shared hosting account using 5.2.17.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://images.jcrew.com/erez4/erez?src=images/eiec/39/39251/39251_WO7826.tif&tmp=prdAr3");
echo "<img src=\"http://images.jcrew.com/erez4/erez?src=images/eiec/39/39251/39251_WO7826.tif&tmp=prdAr3\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
```

I tried increasing the `memory_limit` as was suggested in another question. Getting the sizes of images from other sites works fine both locally and remotely, but for this site, only locally. What might be going on?

Comment: probably because your trying it on a remote file, vs a local, your host may not allow this.From the manual  "It can reference a local file or (**configuration permitting**) a remote file using one of the supported streams. "

Comment: getting the size info works fine on all other sites I've tested both locally and remotely, just not this site specifically.

Comment: trying the url you provided, it redirects, there's the issue, curl can follow redirects get the image and you can check its size locally.

Comment: yes I actually just tried cURL following Anomie's suggestion, and it looks like you're right about forwarding being at least part of the problem. However I'm confused why getting the image size works fine on my local server even though the image link gets forwarded. Does this mean there is some way to make getimagesize() handle forwarding?

Comment: what's your relationship with jcrew?

Comment: @Dagon I do contract work on a fashion-review site that has authorization to use pictures for jcrew products it discusses or promotes, with link to the original product page, and attribution.

Comment: i was thinking they may be able to give you easier access than this method, you could ask them

Comment: that's definitely true. my worry is that since I can't control what sites the script will be used for in the future (or how existing sites decide to store their images in the future), the script would end up failing again, maybe regularly.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your shared hosting may have `allow_url_fopen` disabled. If you haven't already, you should configure [error logging](http://us.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and make sure you're not disabling [error reporting](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in your scripts. It's probably giving you an error message to indicate why it is failing.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled on the remote server. adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to my script I get a result of `Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /hsphere/local/home/url/get_image_size.php on line 4`. The script works fine for all other images I have tested both locally and remotely, but none of the images off this site (remotely, locally they work fine).

Comment: @jela: Oh, it's just one specific site you can't get the images from? It sounds like that one site may be blocking requests from your server. Can you download the image with wget or curl?

Comment: I can download from curl no problem, although I noticed I needed to use `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );` to get the curl to work. I then noticed that visiting the link to the image http://images.jcrew.com/erez4/erez?src=images/eiec/39/39251/39251_WO7826.tif&tmp=prdAr3 forwards me to http://images.jcrew.com/erez4/cache/images_eiec_39_39251_39251_WO7826_tif_1c6e0d0967131a2f.jpg, and if I replace the former link with the latter in my script, the image dimensions can be obtained from the remote server. Could this be related to the problem?

Comment: @jela: I see two possibilities at the moment: either the script behind the first URL is checking your User-Agent (try `ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)')`?), or your shared host somehow has `max_redirects` set to 0 or 1 in the [default stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-default.php) (can you find or make another image URL that redirects to test with?).

Comment: changing the user_agent didn't work. I created a redirecting image on the remote server itself, and the script on the remote server cannot get its image size, but the script on my local server can, so the problem is definitely the redirect. I tried changing max_redirect with `$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'max_redirects'  => 20
    )
);
stream_context_get_default($opts);` without success. I'm still a bit confused on how properly to change the max_redirect option on the default stream.

Comment: @jela: Hmm, I can't find a way to change the stream context for `getimagesize`. It doesn't seem to honor changes made to the default. You might have to use `file_get_contents` or the like to download the image and either write it to a local file for `getimagesize` or just use `imagecreatefromstring` to convert it to an image and then `imagesx` and `imagesy` to get the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether [`allow-url-fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` I get a result of `Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /hsphere/local/home/url/get_image_size.php on line 4` when attempting to get image sizes off this site running the script on the remote server, but not when running the script on my local server. getting images from other sites works fine both locally and remotely for other all other sites I have tested.